# SQL Select runs endless when comparing rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ~800,000 rows. I'm trying to run the following statement, aiming to select certain rows and inserting them into another table.

```
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT n2.* FROM t1 AS n1, t1 AS n2 
 WHERE n1.card_version_id > n2.card_version_id 
  AND n1.card_id = n2.card_id
  AND n1.user_id = n2.user_id;
```

The Query runs for over two hours now, but I do not get any error. I have stopped it before, which also gave me no feedback (Error: Canceled after < 0,1ms).

I'm new to SQL, so I would be happy if anyone could point out to me what I could be doing wrong and if there's probably a better way to do that. I'm sorry if this is trivial, but I could not manage to find an explanation anywhere (probably because I'm not even sure what to look for)

EDIT: These are both tables (same structure)

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`card_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ard_version_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`amount_have` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount_want` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=830447 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`card_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`card_version_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`amount_have` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount_want` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What happens if you run the SELECT part alone? How many rows are returned, how long time does it take?

Comment: do the tables have proper indexes / primary keys?

Comment: could you post the DDL for the involved tables?

Comment: I just saw I made a mistake here in the FROM statement - I try to compare two instances of the same table - it's correct in my query though. I just tried to shorten the names here.
If I run only the SELECT statement it also does not finish. If I interrupt it, it gives me the time it has run though.
The table has a column 'id', which is primary key.

Comment: We can't help you unless you us more details, e.g. table definitions of `t1` and `t2`, their row counts

Comment: i added the table definitions

Comment: You are selecting every record as often as there exists a higher `card_version_id` for its `card_id` and `user_id`. Is this desired? It sounds queer.

Comment: I want to eliminate duplicate records where user_id AND card_id is the same, in that case I want to select the record with the lower card_version_id. Does that make sense to you? So that's the way I tried to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Reason for your query taking more time is: **Cross Join**

As i can see, you are doing want to do the `self join` on table '`T1`' and you are doing this with the help of cross join (`n1,n2`). `The result of the cross join is (no of rows * no of columns)`.
Replace the `cross join` with (`inner or equi join`), it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO t2 
SELECT  n1.card_version_id
        ,n1.card_id
        ,n1.user_id
        --add all other columns of table
FROM t1 n1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT id,MAX(card_version_id)
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY id
) n2
ON n1.id = n2.id and n1.card_version_id = n2.card_version_id
```

Comment: This gives me an Error 'Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I did not do that, referrenced all columns but id

Comment: Re-try with my edits. Sorry for the previous answer, I was in a hurry to answer and completely jinxed that. This is OK.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that still gives me an Error. First Syntax error near 'table...'. When I remove table keyword and just use the name (t1 in first case, t2 in second case) I get a new Error: Unknown column 't2.card_version_id' in 'on clause' - this column is definetely there

Comment: Sorry again (trying to aswer while working..), you have already named your tables t1,t2 and in the query I assumed the name "table" for t1. Now I fixed the table aliases plus I have accidentally selected card_id instead of card_version_id in the subquery, hence the error for unknown column. Now you will be fine, sorry for the incovenience

Comment: Thanks for your effort! it still throws the same error, but I might be able to work something out of your suggestion - I'll let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: It must be something minor. In any case this is the standard way of choosing rows with max value on some of the columns. Furthermore, don't forget we make a self join on t1 (with aliases n1 and n2) - t2 is irrelevant on select. So you can't possibly receive error for t2 table...!